# Creating classes

Tags: c#, oop

This might seem like a very trivial question to more experienced c# developers but please keep in mind I'am a beginner to the c# language but getting through it very well.

However I have came to a stumbling block regarding creating c# classes. I understand the whole concept of the intrinsic details on how to create the class i.e class is like a blueprint in which you create objects from in which there data is stored in fields in which you use constructors to initialize them (or default) and behaviours are performed in the form of methods bla bla etc etc.

However the question that I have is in regards to the purpose of creating your own classes in c#. I was wondering if we create our own classes like the ones that are available in the .net framework,  I.e if the .Net framework hasn't got a class that wee need, so do wee then just create our own class defining the functionality that I need.

Is this the only purpose of creating classes or is this way more focused on creating DLL's, and I am missing something ?

Any ideas tips hints or expansions would be great (in laymen's Terms).

Comment: Classes have nothing to do with DLLs. You can have classes within DLLs and make them public, but you can have classes without DLLs.

Comment: *Too broad* seems incorrect to me. I would agree this is *off-topic* because it's a question that's more about concepts rather than actual coding issues. OP would have more chances on Programmers Stack Exchange. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if the .Net framework hasn't got a class that wee need, so do wee then just create our own class defining the functionality that I need.

Yes.

Comment: +1 This is by far the best *and* shortest answer i've seen for a long time :) Nailed it!

Comment: Sooo... this answers what's the point of making classes?

Comment: @Crono: Strictly speaking, the question was not asking about the point of creating classes (which I would agree is *too broad*), but whether the suspicion of the OP about what's an important point was correct. Which it was, which is what this answer states. (Also, how curious: So far, I had thought that no answer can be marked as accepted once a question has been closed.)